# Gravitational wave equations worked out

Tags: general-relativity, resource-recommendations, gravitational-waves, linearized-theory

Is there a website where [gravitational wave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_wave) equations are worked out numerically?

I would like to experiment with mass configurations but can't find examples.

Comment: as far as I know, they are too complicated to solve. Except for some special cases. I think, even numerically it will be difficult, since you'd be interested in great spatial lengths in which you have to compute all 40 components of the equation quite precisely.

Comment: It requires enormous supercomputing facilities to do such calculations.

Comment: The preparation for such calculations are approx. 6-8 semesters of university level physics and a neck for some serious theory. You also wouldn't want to start from scratch but build on code that others have already written. At the end of the day, what are you trying to learn that has not been published, yet? The emitted power of gravitational dipoles can be found in many textbooks on GR. If that is what you are interested in, no need for a computer, there are good approximations for that for all but the final few moments of the system.

Comment: Thanks to all who commented for providing me this important reality check.  My interest it's primarily one of curiosity not professional work.  It sounds like even experimenting with basic configurations is beyond my resources.  Thanks for saving me the frustration.

Answer (score 1):

The topic is a bit too broad. If you want to look at gravitational wave waveforms coming from e.g. binaries then Post-Newtonian approach is usually sufficient and there are many codes for that out there.

If you want gravitational wave emission worked out in any system it might become a bit troublesome.

I would suggest looking into [lalsuite developed by the LIGO collaboration](https://www.lsc-group.phys.uwm.edu/daswg/docs/howto/lal-install.html), and especially the python interface to it. It is not too easy to use but you can plot binary waveforms with it.

It does require you to have a bit of patience as well as programming skills.

Comment: Thanks, i was specifically interested in understanding what might happen in a crystalline structure of exposed to high frequency gravitational waves when the frequency was some submultiple of the the inter-planar distance if the crystal.  Iron, for example has 42 nanometers as its interplanar distance -- which equates 7 petahertz grav waves.  Obviously, creating them would be impossible, but kilohertz might be possible -- though obviously thw amplitude would be small fir any laboratory created waves.  The question is, could resonance amplify them in the way that is done in lasers.    Thanks